# Change canvas img.src from text input

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a default image inside canvas. I want to be able to paste another image source in a text input and update the img.src when I click the button.
Here is the html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="400"></canvas>
  ...
<label for="image">Paste the img url here</label>
<input type="text" name="pic" id="image">
<button onclick="updateImg()">Submit img</button>
```

and javascript:

```
...
var image = "https://www.whatever.com/image.png";
var img = new Image();
img.src = image;
img.onload = function() {
  draw(this);
};
function updateImg() {
  image = document.getElementById("image").value;
}
...
```

What I am doing wrong?

p.s. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4):

You have to draw image after loading.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="400"></canvas>
    ...
<label for="image">Paste the img url here</label>
<input type="text" name="pic" id="image">
<button onclick="updateImg()">Submit img</button>


<script>
  function updateImg() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0);
    };

    imageObj.src = document.getElementById("image").value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't work. I draw it using this function and isn't updated: function draw(img) {
  var portrait = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var canvas = portrait.getContext('2d'); ... }